# Can Multiple threads run parallel in a multi-core processor

Tags: java, multithreading

In a multi threaded environment,

```
Single core processor
```

When two threads execute in a single core processor, then the two threads execute concurrently.

```
Multi-core(Dual core) processor
```

When two threads execute in a multi core processor, then these the two threads will execute in parallel.  Is my understanding is correct?

Comment: this is with respect to java multithreading concept

Comment: Maybe, but not necessarily. It's up to the OS. The OS can decide that 2 threads will simply timeshare a single core, and just swaps back and forth between them.

Comment: You understand that even single cores have multiple pipelines these days, and that they are often able to run 2, 4, 8 threads in parallel?

Comment: Two threads running "concurrently" means that both were started before either one of them finished. So, any time you have different threads running at the same time on different processors, they are both running in parallel, _and_ running concurrently. Any time you have parallelism, you also have concurrency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theoretically they can be executed in parallel. In fact this depends on some other factors. For example, you are not alone on your system. There are other processes. They can require CPU time as well, so there is a chance that your threads will not get the time slot on time and your threads in fact will be executed sequentially.

Comment: sequentially or concurrently?

Comment: Concurrently == in parallel

Comment: @AlexR Concurrency does not imply parallelism. Parallelism implies Concurrency.